# Running 2 instances of WebDriver (WebStorm Protractor)

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, webstorm

I'm trying to run automated tests using Protractor on WebStorm on Chrome and Firefox.

I've set up the environment and everything looks fine unless I'm trying to run it on both Chrome and Firefox. Works perfectly fine on Chrome itself but not on both.

This is my `config.js`:

```
exports.config = {
    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['**/*.spec.*'],
    multiCapabilities: [
    {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    },
    {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }]
};
```

This is the error I see in the console:

> [15:07:02] I/launcher - Running 2 instances of WebDriver

Comment: That is not an error.  The `I` in `I/launcher` equates to "Info".  `E` would be error, i.e. `E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: That doesn't really help or change anything

Comment: What I'm saying is the details you have given do not shed light on the problem.  You need to elaborate more and provide the correlated logs.  What you have provided is expected behavior... it will always log that line.